# The best barber in town

Tags: strategy, situation

You are in a town with one barber shop and two barbers, one with good hair and one with terrible hair, there are no towns nearby so everyone in town must get there hair cut at this barber shop.

Which barber should you choose to cut your hair?

Comment: What does the "layton" tag refer to?

Comment: Maybe it is a question from the Professor Layton game series?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is:

> Choose the barber with terrible hair.

The reason is:

> The barber with good hair can not cut his own hair and has to rely on the barber with terrible hair. This results in his obviously good.
>  For the other barber, it is the other way round: the barber with good hair is not able to give a good hair cut.

Comment: Darn! beat me to it with 46 seconds :<

Comment: "Another puzzle solved!"

Answer (score 9):

> Go ask someone in the city with a good hair cut "From whom they did their hair cut"?

By that you can understand who is a good barber.

Since,

> Some barbers cut their own hair, while some not. So the perfect way to understand who is the good barber is asking someone in the town with a good hair cut.

Answer (score 3):

You should:

> Get your hair cut by the barber with good hair

Reason:

> Everyone knows that barbers cut their own hair. I do

Comment: Are you a barber?

Comment: @MarkBannister Not really. I worked for a few summers (2006-2009) at a barbershop and picked up this trick.

Answer (score 1):

You should get your hair cut by:

> The barber with the terrible hair, the only one who could have cut his hair, was the other barber, who isn't very good at his job as we can see at the other barbers hair!